# Is Rails + Faye a good RIA platform? Or do I need raw node.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, faye

Is Faye "simply" a publish/receive system for messages or can you build entire rich applications with the combination Rails/Faye?

Part of my website is a fantasy league draft room.

The room itself needs to be programmed to do certain things at certain intervals; such as allowing each team captain 15 seconds to pick a player for his team from a list, before moving on to the next player.

The room also needs to safeguard access; only those teams that are in the league may access the room, and only at a certain date/time.

Can I program all these actions in a Faye setup? Or will I be better off getting this built in Node.js as a realtime app that communicates with my rails app?

Need a nudge in the right direction...

Comment: if your requirement is not too big you can use  faye if you are using rails.or other wise you can use nodejs with framework like express,but it's upto you you can decide your stack.